# Twitter-bootstrap navbar dropdown behaving oddly (not working on mobile, not showing on desktop)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom

The navbar is being super weird on this site that I created!

When I shrink the page it disappears. Also it doesn't even work on mobile. I have no idea why this is happening, I regret not testing after every change...agh. =(

Perhaps any CSS/DOM ninjas can be of service!

http://finitecapital.com/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your custom style:

```
.container {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
}
```

Remove that and all will be fine. You should not change main bootstrap classes which define grid behaviour like container and col (span). If you want your container to be different size you should check bootstrap documents and see the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to include responsive css add this line then it will work in mobile

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: And don't forget, bootstrap need JQuery to running well, so make sure you include the JQuery **before** the css.